# is IBAction mandatory to reflect a method on Interface Builder?

Tags: ibaction

What is the difference between below two methods, both are meant for mapping through Interface builder

```
- (void) showNYTimes:(id)sender
          and 
- (IBAction) showNYTimes:(id)sender
```

Both are working perfectly for my requirement, I am able to map both ways on IB. But which one to opt, is IBAction meant for only readability of code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`IBAction` is `#define`d as void, so as far as Objective C is concerned they're the same; it's meant to be a signal to Interface Builder that this particular method is available to be hooked up to a view. ["IBAction - Type qualifier used by Interface Builder to synchronize actions added programmatically with its internal list of action methods defined for a project."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Constants/Reference/reference.html)

So it's more than just readability; it's a declaration that's meaningful to IB. I'm not sure how you were able to map your `(void)` method in Interface Builder, though. Only `(IBAction)` methods have the little circle in the gutter for me.